# Position of child after canvas is difference between chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html, canvas

```
<div>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="679" height="679" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
 </canvas>
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

The input box is on the top of canvas when I use chrome.
but when I use safari, the input box is below canvas and looks very ugly.

I want add a input box to canvas. So how can I fix it for Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap them with a `block` element:

https://jsfiddle.net/5e8vj3k4/

```
<div>
  <div>
   <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="679" height="679" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
 </div>
</div>
```